# how to extract string from string-number combination rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, ruby-on-rails-4

```
my-test-string-4-23
```

From the above string how can i extract only string that is only `my-test-string`

I tries to_s method but it returns whole string as it is.

Comment: what are you looking for here?  only the first three words?  all the words but no numbers?  a certain number of characters?

Comment: Not only first three words, words may vary. But the integers at the end is standard.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Split it on numbers only, split returns an array, then gsub to remove the last "-"

```
str = "my-test-string-4-23"

str.split(/(\d+)/)[0].gsub(/\-$/, '')
```

Will return

```
"my-test-string"
```

Answer (score 0):

your_string.match('[\D-]')[0].[0..-1] might work. It'll return the first instance of non-decimals and dashes, then drop the last -